# python merge to documents line by line by way concatenation

Tags: python, python-2.7, merge, concatenation

How can i join these two text documents?

**document 1:**

```
1000001 10:0.471669 250:0.127552 30:0.218773 64:0.249413
1000002 130:0.0839656 107:0.185613 30:0.446355 110:0.38011
1000003 1:0.0835855 1117:0.0647112 302:0.0851354 46:0.0601825 48:0.098907 516:0.167713
```

**document 2:**

```
1000001 161:0.115664 207:0.136537 294:0.0974809 301:0.199868
1000002
1000003 555:0.0585849 91:0.0164101
```

**result:**

```
1000001 10:0.471669 250:0.127552 30:0.218773 64:0.249413 161:0.115664 207:0.136537 294:0.0974809 301:0.199868
1000002 130:0.0839656 107:0.185613 30:0.446355 110:0.38011
1000003 1:0.0835855 1117:0.0647112 302:0.0851354 46:0.0601825 48:0.098907 516:0.167713 555:0.0585849 91:0.0164101
```

**explanation:**
**document 1** and **document 2** both have the same structure and they have the same number of lines.
 Each line starts with a number (the same number in both documents), and then we have several items in each line which are made up of a number+colon+a decimal number: 
*example* **10:0.471669**
these item combinations are unique, what I want to do is to merge them together: take the items from the second document for each line and put it in the corresponding line of the first document.
*note:*
the initial number at the beginning and the items from one another are separated by a single space.

### update

here is my attempt:

```
dat1 = {}
with open('doc1') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        dat1[line.split(' ')[0]] = line.strip().split(' ')[1:]

dat2 = {}
with open('doc2') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        key = line.split(' ')[0]
        dat2[key] = line.split(' ')[0]

for key in dat1.keys():
    print("%s,%s,%s" % (key, str.join(' ', dat1[key]), str.join(' ', dat2[key])))
```

but i am getting traceback error of index out of range at line 9.

### update 2:

here is the corrected code:

```
dat1 = {}
with open('stem.data') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        dat1[line.split(' ')[0]] = line.strip().split(' ')[1:]

dat2 = {}
with open('stem.info') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        key = line.split(' ')[0]
        dat2[key] = line.split(' ')[1:]

for key in dat1.keys():
    print("%s %s %s" % (key, str.join(' ', dat1[key]), str.join(' ', dat2[key])))
```

but again I get an error in the last line! However apparently the concatenation is being done as I visually checked few lines; but stops because of the error. 
 could you please let me know what is wrong here?

Comment: Please include the code that you tried and explain the issues you are facing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: As you write your code look into things like string split, lists, dictionaries, and for loops.

Comment: You are not *joining* two files. You are creating a new file with data gathered from two files. Therefore, you have to parse both files and then create a new file. What have you tried?

Comment: @zvone I updated my question and added my attempt at it. could you please have a look and tell me the problem is.

Comment: At least this is wrong: `key = line.split(' ')[0].split(' ')[1]` because `line.split(' ')[0]` is the first word - it has no spaces, so doing `.split(' ')[1]` on that will fail.

Comment: @zvone could you please suggest a correction or an answer please?

Comment: @zvone I get a KeyError, https://wiki.python.org/moin/KeyError why is it happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
for key in (set(dat1) | set(dat2)):
    print(key, ' '.join(dat1.get(key, '')), ' '.join(dat2.get(key, '')))
```

That's how you apply `join` to arrays (and you don't need string formatting here).

`for key in (set(dat1) | set(dat2))` will iterate all the keys in both dictionaries.

The use of `.get` ensures that in case only one file has that key, only his content will be chosen (and will not throw an error).

---

Also, `for line in f.readlines():` can be shortened for `for line in f:`. That will iterate the lines (separated by new-lines) the same way.

Comment: how can I save my output into a file instead of printing it?

Comment: i still get a keyerror https://wiki.python.org/moin/KeyError ! why is that?

Comment: this is happening when the document two KEY doesn't have anything to be added to the first document. like in the example above.